# R: How to read fixed width datafile where the data is concatenated into two sets, stacked on top in one file

Tags: r, dplyr, fixed-width, read.fwf

Hopefully the title make sense.

In essence, there are two datasets in one file.

Row 1 has the headings, by loc, for dataset1. Then lines 2-1500 are the entries for those locs.

At row 1501 is the heading, by loc, for dataset2. Then lines 1502-3001 are the entries for those locs.

How can I read in a fixed with file with these properties, providing the header spacings for each dataset (and the point at which dataset2 starts).

Comment: Why not just manually remove the headers at row 1501?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two methods:

### Using the `skip` and `nrows` arguments:

```
first <- read.table("file", header = T, nrows = 1500)
second <- read.table("file", header = T, skip=1501, nrows = 1500)
```

### Reading in the entire file then splitting it up:

```
allLines <- read.table("file", header = T)
first <- allLines[1:1500, ]
second <- allLines[1502:3002, ]
names(second) <- allLines[1501, ] ## or colnames if working with a matrix
```